# How can I get the android version of phone if i only have its Model?

Tags: android

Before building our app, we want to know The Android versions that we are going to target so we made a survey in order to get informations about the users and their smartphone.
the users may not know their android version but they surely know the Model of their smartphone.

so How can we get approximately the android version of a Phone based on its Model?

(board, database , excel file ... so i can automate the study )

Thank's!

Comment: use `android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` in your code to get know android version ... if you are searching for database with android versions and models, then SO is a wrong place to ask ...

Comment: @Selvin, Question states "_before building our app_", so there is no code yet.

Comment: Then it is not programming related, then it is off-topic for SO.

Comment: Also, many users may not know the model of their phone either (my grandma doesn't, for example). You could ask people to check the version number in Settings > About Phone though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can refer to website like : 
http://www.gsmarena.com/
http://www.phonearena.com/
For example: http://www.gsmarena.com/motorola_moto_g_(2nd_gen)-6647.php gives you all the specs of Moto G 2nd Gen Android phone. 
You can write a WebScraping program against aforementioned websites and make your own database, which you can use to further automate your needs.

Comment: WebScraping !! thank you for the idea!!

Answer (score 2):

The best you can do is implement Google Analytics in your app, you not only will get that info but a lot of useful info. Check the [guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/) to know how to implement it.

Comment: thank you! i'll check it